# POST request XML malformed

Tags: php, xml

I have a problem with an EPP XML request. I have been getting a `Command Syntax Error` response from the API for quite some time now. I've been in contact with the technical department who just recently responded that my XML is being received as malformed, being split in the middle. I don't know why.

I compile the PHP to XML using the `DOMDocument` class. I return every XML build method using `__toString()` which returns `$this->saveXML();` which dumps the tree as string. I then send a POST request. Every other method works fine, but not this.

Code here:

https://github.com/OssiPesonen/epp_depo

I actually dump my XML using:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo $xml;
die();
```

And every time it gives me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
  <command>
    <create>
      <contact:create xmlns:contact="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:contact-1.0">
        <contact:id>1</contact:id>
        <contact:role>5</contact:role>
        <contact:type>1</contact:type>
        <contact:postalInfo type="loc">
          <contact:isfinnish>1</contact:isfinnish>
          <contact:firstname>Essi</contact:firstname>
          <contact:lastname>Esimerkki Oy</contact:lastname>
          <contact:name>HR</contact:name>
          <contact:org>Esimerkki Oy</contact:org>
          <contact:birthDate>2005-04-03T00:00:00.0Z</contact:birthDate>
          <contact:identity>123423A123F</contact:identity>
          <contact:registernumber>20824760</contact:registernumber>
          <contact:addr>
            <contact:street>Test Street</contact:street>
            <contact:pc>00000</contact:pc>
            <contact:cc>FI</contact:cc>
            <contact:city>City</contact:city>
          </contact:addr>
        </contact:postalInfo>
        <contact:voice x="1234">+358401234567</contact:voice>
        <contact:email>testi@testi.fi</contact:email>
        <contact:legalemail>testi@testi.fi</contact:legalemail>
        <contact:disclose flag="0">
          <contact:addr/>
          <contact:email/>
        </contact:disclose>
      </contact:create>
    </create>
    <clTRID>E1144-588371f25ab80</clTRID>
  </command>
</epp>
```

This doesn't look malformed, right? Yet, the technical support responded to me, that after `<contact:city>` was split before the closing tag:

```
contact:city>
            <contact:sp>VA</contact:sp>
            <contact:pc>20166-6503</contact:pc>
            <contact:cc>US</contact:cc>
          </contact:addr>
        </contact:postalInfo>
        <contact:voice x="1234">+3581231234</contact:voice>
        <contact:fax>+04040as</contact:fax>
        <contact:email>jdoe@example.com</contact:email>
        <contact:legalemail>jdoe@example.com</contact:legalemail>
        <contact:disclose flag="0">
          <contact:addr/>
          <contact:email/>
        </contact:disclose>
      </contact:create>
    </create>
    <clTRID>E1144-5867f93f6503a</clTRID>
  </command>
</epp>
05-04-03T22:00:00.0Z</contact:birthDate>
          <contact:identity>010188-123A</contact:identity>
          <contact:registernumber>123456-7</contact:registernumber>
          <contact:addr>
            <contact:street>123 Example Dr.</contact:street>
            <contact:street></contact:street>
            <contact:street></contact:street>
            <contact:city>Dulles</
```

Any ideas what might cause this? Because I can't see it.

**Edit**

After exhausting my options I've uploaded the code to Github to be viewed.

https://github.com/OssiPesonen/epp_depo

Comment: I use DOMDocument for EPP myself and have never had problems you describe. Ensure you are not using i.e. old version of PHP/DOMDocument  as maybe it's not your fault. Also you quoted just XML not the code, so this quite partially useful

Comment: For purposes of ruling something in or out as the problem: consider removing the namespace *xmlns="..."* from the XML and see if it works that way. ...or maybe you get a different error message.

Comment: This has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer was simple, yet I cannot understand why it's the solution.

I basically removed all the failsafes from the send() method and  leaving just this:

```
private function send($buffer)
{
    if(fwrite($this->socket, $buffer)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I don't really know what it was that cut the XML string in the previous one, but this will do for our platform.